# Can I use MEF to add content to a vs2010 right-click context menu?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, contextmenu, mef, extensibility, maf

Specifically dealing with extending the vs2010 right-click context menu. 
Can I use MEF to add content to a right-click context menu. I know that was something that was supposedly in the works back in 2009 so I figured maybe there is now or, am I stuck with MAF for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Managed Menu Extensions](http://mme.codeplex.com/) to write context menus for the solution explorer as MEF parts.

Comment: Okay I'm impressed +1* aCrapLoad if i could

Answer (score 2):

No MEF cannot be used in Visual Studio 2010 to extend the right click menu system.  Doing that requires a Visual Studio Package and likely an additional VSCT file.  The good news is though they can be packaged together in a single DLL.